# Restricting dropwizard admin page

Tags: dropwizard

How to authenticate Dropwizard admin portal, so as to restrict normal users from accessing it?
Please help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your config, you can set `adminUsername` and `adminPassword` under `http` like so:

```
http:
  adminUsername: user1234
  adminPassword: pass5678
```

Comment: Just make sure you don't store these in a public repo like GitHub... :-)

Comment: do you know if there is also a possibility to do that in the config file for DW 0.7.1?

Comment: Not working for DW 0.8.4, those fields are not mentioned in configuration spec.

Answer (score 15):

For DW 0.7 my approach would be:

```
public class AdminConstraintSecurityHandler extends ConstraintSecurityHandler {

    private static final String ADMIN_ROLE = "admin";

    public AdminConstraintSecurityHandler(final String userName, final String password) {
        final Constraint constraint = new Constraint(Constraint.__BASIC_AUTH, ADMIN_ROLE);
        constraint.setAuthenticate(true);
        constraint.setRoles(new String[]{ADMIN_ROLE});
        final ConstraintMapping cm = new ConstraintMapping();
        cm.setConstraint(constraint);
        cm.setPathSpec("/*");
        setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator());
        addConstraintMapping(cm);
        setLoginService(new AdminMappedLoginService(userName, password, ADMIN_ROLE));
    }
}

public class AdminMappedLoginService extends MappedLoginService {

    public AdminMappedLoginService(final String userName, final String password, final String role) {
        putUser(userName, new Password(password), new String[]{role});
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @Override
    protected UserIdentity loadUser(final String username) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void loadUsers() throws IOException {
    }
}
```

and using them in the way:

```
environment.admin().setSecurityHandler(new AdminConstraintSecurityHandler(...))
```

Comment: This answer does not work for later versions of DW/Jetty. See my answer below that works as of DW 1.2.2

Answer (score 4):

Newer Jetty versions do not have `MappedLoginService`, so @Kamil's answer no longer works. I have modified their answer to get it working as of Dropwizard 1.2.2:

```
public class AdminConstraintSecurityHandler extends ConstraintSecurityHandler {

    private static final String ADMIN_ROLE = "admin";

    public AdminConstraintSecurityHandler(final String userName, final String password) {
        final Constraint constraint = new Constraint(Constraint.__BASIC_AUTH, ADMIN_ROLE);
        constraint.setAuthenticate(true);
        constraint.setRoles(new String[]{ADMIN_ROLE});
        final ConstraintMapping cm = new ConstraintMapping();
        cm.setConstraint(constraint);
        cm.setPathSpec("/*");
        setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator());
        addConstraintMapping(cm);
        setLoginService(new AdminLoginService(userName, password));
    }

    public class AdminLoginService extends AbstractLoginService {

        private final UserPrincipal adminPrincipal;
        private final String adminUserName;

        public AdminLoginService(final String userName, final String password) {
            this.adminUserName = Objects.requireNonNull(userName);
            this.adminPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(userName, new Password(Objects.requireNonNull(password)));
        }


        @Override
        protected String[] loadRoleInfo(final UserPrincipal principal) {
            if (adminUserName.equals(principal.getName())) {
                return new String[]{ADMIN_ROLE};
            }
            return new String[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected UserPrincipal loadUserInfo(final String userName) {
            return adminUserName.equals(userName) ? adminPrincipal : null;
        }
    }
}
```