# Dropwizard - Request Filter for health check

Tags: jersey, dropwizard

I have set up healthcheck in dropwizard and they are working fine. Now, I want only authorized users to access the healthcheck. When I created a custom filter and added it to the admin it was never used. I added like this:

```
environment.admin().addFilter("AdminFilter",new AdminFilter());
```

How does one add a filter to healthcheck request?
I am running admin on port 8081. My yaml looks like this

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not register your filter: addFilter() returns only mapper object, which must be used to map filter in web context (to some pattern or around some servlet)

For example,

```
environment.admin().addFilter("AdminFilter",new AdminFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

Will register filter for everything in the admin context.

And here is an example of how to configure basic auth for admin context https://stackoverflow.com/a/23828705/5186390