# Security for Dropwizard admin servlet (version 1.1.1)

Tags: java, dropwizard

I'm using `Dropwizard (1.1.1)`.

My security context is defined as such:

```
    environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
            .setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator())
            .setAuthorizer(new BasicAuthorizer())
            .setRealm("SECURITY REALM")
            .buildAuthFilter()));

    environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
    environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
```

Recently I moved my Admin page into my web application. Code is right here:

```
    environment.getApplicationContext().setAttribute(
            MetricsServlet.METRICS_REGISTRY,
            environment.metrics());
    environment.getApplicationContext().setAttribute(
            HealthCheckServlet.HEALTH_CHECK_REGISTRY,
            environment.healthChecks());
    environment.getApplicationContext().addServlet(
            new NonblockingServletHolder(new AdminServlet()), "/admin/*");
```

How can I add security context to `Dropwizard admin servlet`?

I have already viewed this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987911/restricting-dropwizard-admin-page), but nothing seems to be working. Looks like everything in that answer is deprecated.

Comment: For reference, the correct way to get new attention on an old question in this case is to offer a bounty on the old question for a new, up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the admin servlet is a plain old servlet, not a Jersey resource. Given that you are creating a new admin servlet (are you disabling the default admin context?) in the application context, you can simply register a servlet filter to the application context like this:

```
environment.getApplicationContext().addFilter(new FilterHolder(new AdminServletFilter()), "/admin/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
```

Your `AdminServletFilter` can authenticate the user any way you like, for example if you want to do basic auth, use this [implementation](https://gist.github.com/neolitec/8953607).

That said, if your intention is to move your admin servlet to run on the same port as your application connector, the better way to do it is via config:

```
server:
  type: simple
  adminContextPath: /admin
  applicationContextPath: /
  connector:
    type: http
    port: 8080
```

Also, I have updated the question you linked to with a security handler implementation that works for the latest Dropwizard version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48757093/1314028). With this in place, you can protect the admin servlet by registering the security handler:

```
environment.admin().setSecurityHandler(new AdminConstraintSecurityHandler("admin", "supersecret"));
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot!